# Dynamics AX 2009 How to change customer invoice layout/printing?

Tags: printing, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I'd like to change the default customer invoice print to something else. Add an image to the head, change the layout, change the columns, well everything in fact.

Can someone explain how to start this, or maybe point me to some tutorial or reference about this?

So far all I found was ways to create new reports, but I'd like to change the default invoice print, not create something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default sales invoice report is in AOT>Reports>SalesInvoice. This is not an easy report to modify so it is recomendable to add a new design to it instead of modifying the Standard one. This way you always can revert changes to the standard.

You have more information about AX reporting at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb427701(AX.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

For Dynamics 2009 some of the basics on report modification are actually in the Microsoft Certification books for DEV I, II, III and IV. There are a couple cook books for AX worth looking into as well. MSDN/PartnerSource is always good.

Another approach is to open the "reports" node in the AOT and locate the "tutorial_" prefixed reports which have been created to demonstrate report modification.

ex:
tutorial_Date
tutorial_Joins
tutorial_HelloWorld
tutorial_Prompt